# javascript splice

Tags: javascript

I have an array MyArray and I want to remove one element at position i.

I tried:

```
MyArray = MyArray.splice(i, 1);
```

but it's returning the element I want to remove, instead of the array without the element I want to remove.

I''m sure it's a simple fix, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change

```
MyArray = MyArray.splice(i, 1);
```

into

```
MyArray.splice(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 11):

You should read the [documentation on splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> ### Summary
>
> Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

The original array gets changed, rather than returning a new array with the specified elements removed. `MyArray.splice(i, 1);` should be enough.

Comment: ok, thanks; hopefully the question title will be seo optimized so others will get to it without having to sort through the entire documentation:)

Answer (score 3):

splice() is a destructive method in that it has side effects aside from returning value.  While it returns the removed element, it modifies the actual array you've passed in.

```
alert("Before: " + MyArray);
MyArray.splice(i, 1);
alert("After: " + MyArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

`splice` edits the array in place.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// arr is [1, 2, 3, 4];
var el = arr.splice(0, 1);
// el is [1], arr is now [2, 3, 4].
```

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much got it! however don't assign it to a new value.. just use your existing array.

```
MyArray.splice(i, 1);
Something = MyArray;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, the splice method edits the existing array and returns the removed element(s) as a separate array.  Check MyArray after your splice.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, especially since I only wanted to remove a specific item in the array, not all items matching that item.

I created this extension for KO observable arrays, which seems to work.  I haven't tried it with arrays of objects yet, but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

When I was first learning KO, I had a very hard time dealing with Arrays, so I hope this will be useful to others:

JavaScript:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.removeAt = function (index) {
  this.valueWillMutate();
  this.splice(index, 1);
  this.valueHasMutated();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Answers">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data"/>
    <button 
        data-bind="click: function(){ $parent.Answers.removeAt($index()) }"                          
        title="Remove"
    >X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax

```
array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])
```

### Description

Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

### Return

An array containing the removed elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

from [Array splice method - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

here's another way (if you still want to set it as a variable and keep the original array the same):

```
// example array
var foo = ['1', '13', '44', '17', '17', '19', '1', '7', '17'];

// lets say we want to remove one of the 17s from the array
// convert array to string, do replacements, then convert back
var bar = foo.join().replace('17', '').replace(/\,\,/gi, ',').split(',');

// should log ['1', '13', '44', '17', '19', '1', '7', '17']
console.log(bar);
```

depending on how your array is structured, it's sometimes easier to query/manipulate a string instead of array (and sometimes vice-versa)